# Как правильно произносить "пятьдесят"?

Tags: орфоэпия

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно произносить слово "пятьдесят"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

> ...как правильно произносить слово "пятьдесят"?

В *«Большом орфоэпическом словаре русского языка» М. Л. Каленчук, Л. Л. Касаткина, Р. Ф. Касаткиной* (М., 2012) приведены такие варианты произношения:

> ***пя[д'д']есят*** и допустимо: ***пя[д']есят***.

Answer (score 0):

[п' ь д'(долгое) и с' **а** т]

[ь] — звук, который также встречается в таких словах, как [м о р' ь] (море), [г о р' ь] (горе), и похож на сверхкраткий звук [jэ].